# HTML5 Canvas lineTo issue with recursion

Tags: canvas, recursion, binary-search-tree

So, I was bored and decided to make a simple BST, and then I thought it would be neat to draw it on canvas.  I am using in order traversal so it prints the tree in the right order.  If you look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BY6Ap/13/

Here is the method from jsFiddle:

```
BST.prototype._draw = function(ctx, node, x, y, depth) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (node.left != null) {
        ctx.moveTo(x - 100 / depth, y + 50 + depth * 10);
    }
    this._draw(ctx, node.left, x - 100 / depth, y + 50 + depth * 10, depth + 1);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y); 

    this._drawNode(ctx, node, x, y);

    if (node.right != null) {
        ctx.moveTo(x + 100 / depth, y + 50 + depth * 10);
    }
    this._draw(ctx, node.right, x + 100 / depth, y + 50 + depth * 10, depth + 1);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
}

BST.prototype._drawNode = function(ctx, node, x, y) {
    //ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 12, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillText(node.data, x, y);
    //ctx.stroke();
}
```

You can see it being drawn.  The only issue that I have is that the lineTo, or moveTo seems to be trying to draw an extra line horizontal to the right inside the where the node is drawn.  I was wondering if anyone could throw me in a direction to remove that extra line.  I tried multiple things, but none seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just missing `beginPath` when you start drawing.

```
BST.prototype._draw = function(ctx, node, x, y, depth) {
    ctx.beginPath();  //<- this is what you were missing
```

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HgyS/).

Comment: So simple, yet effective.  I can't believe I missed that, thanks.